# How do I replicate my current manual internet configurations in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

My current internet configuration is no longer automatic. Here is a screenshot

[image: screenshot]

of the manual configurations in Windows 8 (which I ditched for 12.04)

How do I set up this configuration in 12.04? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to configure the Network with the Network-Manager GUI in Unity.
I made a Screeshot, and I hope you will understand how to do it, but it is realy easy.

[image: NM Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Try editing `/etc/network/interfaces` to add a section like.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.134
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```